# How to use std::pointer_safety

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, smart-pointers

I just found this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/gc/pointer_safety

But I don't know how to use it.

Is there some simple example?

Comment: you don't. it's for GC writers who happen to write GC for C++.

Comment: It tells you something about [your run-time](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.stc.dynamic.safety#4). I've yet to see it in use.

Comment: No compiler offers `preferred` or `strict` pointer safety AFAIK.